# Dart: Listeners on stream never trigger onError function

Tags: stream, dart, flutter, listener

I am building a flutter app and using Bloc. I am adding a `sink.addError('some error text')` on a stream's sink.

In the Bloc, i have added a listener to the stream, which has functions like `onDone`, `onError`, and the `data`. Now what happens is, everything that i add in a sink, even `sink.addError` is classified as data, and not error. I want to figure out, how to differentiate the data added in sink, and the errors added in sink.addError.

Initially i thought `onError(error){}`, is not getting called. Is it that, the `sink.addError('some error text')` is also considered data in stream. If it is, then i need a way to differentiate data, and error data. Here is some code, to help you get the gist of my question:

```dart
class Bloc extends Object with Validators { 
  final _controller;   
  final DataBloc dataBloc;

  BlocTextField({ this.dataBloc}) : _controller = initMethod(dataBloc);

  //TODO: Issue with Stream.listen where onError is never called   
  static BehaviorSubject<dynamic> initMethod(DataBloc dataBloc) {
    final _controller = new BehaviorSubject<dynamic>();

    _controller.stream.listen((data) {
      print("Data in "+ data);
    }, onError: (error) {
      print("Error in "+ error);
    });

    return _controller;
  }

  //To change data to our Stream using Sink.   
  Function(dynamic) get changeField=> _controller.sink.add;

  //To add field data from Stream.   
  textFieldStream => _controller.stream.transform(validateField());

  dispose() {
     _textFieldController.close();  
  } 
}
```

Now when i try to add data in this stream. Here is my validator

```dart
class Validators {
  validateField() {
    return StreamTransformer<dynamic, dynamic>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (FieldStream, sink) {
        sink.addError("Some error here");
    });
  }
}
```

Console output is: `Data in some error here`.

Here are my flutter doctor results:

```dart
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G3025, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.27.2)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Please let me know, a valid solution!

Comment: That's not how StreamTransformers works. You need to access the streamController first

Comment: @RémiRousselet is it really streamTransformer that you think is wrong? i have access to streamController. In this example, i am just putting a string in my sink errors. It should work, and it does. I get the string in my data. I am just asking how to differentiate data added in sink directly or added as an error in sink. Hope this clears it for you!

Comment: My bad I didn't fully understand your architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your listeners are on the original Stream, not the transformed Stream.

A call to `stream.transform()` returns a *new* stream, it does not alter the original except to add a listener.

You need `textFieldStream.listen(...)` to see the errors.